# how to join 2 tables and show records in tableview

Tags: ios, sql

I have these 2 tables

```
CREATE TABLE "QuestionWithAnswer" ("Date" DATETIME PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL , "Question" TEXT, "Answer" TEXT, "UserAnswer" TEXT, "IsCorrect" BOOL)

CREATE TABLE "Records" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ,"DateWithTime" DATETIME,"UserGivenAnswer" TEXT DEFAULT (null) ,"Correct" TEXT DEFAULT (null) ,"Question_ID" TEXT)
```

i want to join them on date and retreive records and show them in tableview in ios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query will get all the columns in the database where the dates match: `SELECT * FROM QuestionWithAnswer AS Q JOIN Records AS R ON Q.Date=R.DateWithTime;`

Next thing is up to you to create objects of the two tables and parse the fetched SQLite data into the right fields of the respective object.

After that, create a UITableVIew and set the viewcontroller (or a model) as the datasource and just use a list (NSArray, NSDictionary, ..) containing the fetched objects to populate that tableview. There are lots of good tutorials on the net on how to do this.

For your info, this kind of question is quite broad and you cannot expect a full-featured answer since that means creating a lot of code which really isn't the purpose of SO.